# Are there four dimensional generalizations of the Reuleaux triangle and other solids of constant width?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Is there a four dimensional generalization of the Reuleaux triangle? What is it called, and what properties does it have?

Thank you!

Comment: I think that this is an interesting question (although, as the [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/456062) points out, you might have guessed relevant terms for searching the literature), but "does this object exist and what are its properties?" is, I think, far too broad for an MO question (whatever "this object" is).  I would have voted accordingly, but they took away that close reason, so went with a different close vote—but that was the meaning.

Comment: No problem, I am new to this stack exchange. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Usually the generalizations are just called *bodies of constant width.*

But more specifically, this paper

> Lachand‐Robert, Thomas, and Edouard Oudet. "Bodies of constant width in arbitrary dimension." *Mathematische Nachrichten* 280, no. 7 (2007): 740-750.
> [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1002/mana.200510512).

describes a 4D
body of constant width whose 3D‐projection is the *Meissner tetrahedron*,
which is a smoothing of the Reuleaux tetrahedron.
So this is, in a sense, "a four-dimensional generalization of the Reuleaux triangle," as requested by the OP.

[image: 4D Meissner]